# Can I add non-return valve to an existing tap

Tags: plumbing, water, plumbing-fixture

I recently purchased and installed a tap (pics below). I found that if I keep the main tap handle open but keep the outlets closed, I hear hiss sound of the water as if the water is still running.  I ignored this and then water started overflowing from an overhead tank in the attic.

A handy-man told me that the tap hasn't got a non-return valve. I should put a NRV. Is he correct? Can I add an NRV to the existing pipework? Have I bought a wrong type of tap?

[image]
[image]

Comment: When you say "main tap handle", are you referring to the squeeze lever at the end of the sprung hose or are you talking about the temperature/control lever at the fixed base, just above the sink? Which "outlets" are you keeping closed?

Comment: main handle = mixer lever on the left

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cold supply has a higher pressure than the hot which is fed from the tank in the attic.

So you need to fit a not return valve in the hot supply to the tap shown and make sure it is fitted so flow is from the pipe to the tap.